# Sync redux store with react-router route location (update header on route change)

Tags: url-routing, react-redux, react-router-redux

I am using `react-router-redux` and I'm trying to update the header of my app, that receives it's state from the store, whenever the route changes (`@@router/UPDATE_LOCATION`)

Currently I'm dispatching actions in a `componentWillMount` like:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.appActions.setHeader('New Block')
  }
```

When I manually set the header in `componentWillMount` on route `/blocks/new`, and it is a child of a route 'blocks', who both have a different header, it doesn't work when I go back in `history`, because the component of route `blocks` does not mount again, it is *still* mounted. Thus the header is still `New Block`. And not what its own header was before, when `blocks` mounted, and `new` was still unmounted as child.

(And when I try to *reverse time* with the `redux-devtools`, what seems to happen then, every time I go back to a point where a component mounts again, it will dispatch the action again, and the devtool will receive another dispatch.)

The routes:

```
<Route path="begin" component={PlayerBeginContainer}>
    <IndexRoute component={PlayerOverview}/>
       <Route path="blocks" component={PlayerBlocks}>
         <Route path="new" component={PlayerNewBlock}/>
       </Route>
</Route>
...
```

I've tried to sync the store whenever a route changes, but:

```
if (action && action.type === UPDATE_LOCATION) {
 let path = action.payload.pathname.split('/')
 // Laboriously iterate through array to figure out what the new header state should be.
  // i.e. if (1 in split && split[1] === 'routeName')
  // or let lastPath = path[path.length - 1]
  // and getting parentPath would require more checking of whether it is the parent itself or not etc.
  // appHeader = 'routeHeader'
  return Object.assign({}, state, { appHeader: appHeader});
}
```

This gets very tedious when you just need it to trigger on a specific sub-route, 
And I want to avoid making another nested structure, while I already have that defined in the router.

In the header I can't use anything other than `this.props.location.pathname` either to try and figure out which route i'm on, and the components themselves should not bother with setting the header themselves (i.e. in `componentWillMount`).

Last option would be to use the router `onEnter`, but I'd like to keep the router clean, but perhaps I need to compromise on this.

Is there something I'm missing here? Or some sort of lib that can help me with this?

TL;DR: How can I make my `header` component aware of which route we are on, without having to break down the `location.pathname` to figure out where we are?

Comment: You can just get the entire location state as a prop to your relevant react component in ``mapStateToProp`` by picking up the location piece of your state that you've given to ``react-router-redux``. Once you have it as a prop, you should be able to do what you want. It might end up being splitting the pathname again but it seems to be cleaner than listening to the UPDATE_LOCATION action.

Comment: Does this help: https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#how-do-i-access-router-state-in-a-container-component ?

Comment: @iamnat, thing is, that I'm not using `params.id` or `query.filter`, so my header still has to `.split('/')` the pathname for each case.

Answer (score 0):

This is code from one of my codebases. In this app i use hash history, but i think you could do same thing with [other history objects](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) too.

```
import {hashHistory} from 'react-router';
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux';

const history = syncHistoryWithStore(hashHistory, store);
history.listen(location => {
   // here you can do something after location is updated
});

<Router history={history}>
 ....
</Router>
```

and then in you components you can get some info from state.routing:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    current: state.routing.locationBeforeTransitions.pathname,
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

To change route from some component, do this:

```
import {push} from 'react-router-redux';
this.props.dispatch(push('/route'));
```