# How to set Header Fixed for all components only components should render in the body section header should be same as fixed

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

How to set Header Fixed for all components and  only components should be render in the body section moreover header title also need to show dynamically based on components renders in body section
is it possible through Router or from redux

Comment: Not following you. Can you share some of your current code or a fiddle to show us what you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is shown in the first example of the [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router#whats-it-look-like) Docs.

You want to wrap all routes in one main, container route usually called `App`:

```js
render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <Route path="about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Inside the `App` component you can then make use of `this.props.children` to show the components based on the route.

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HeaderAlwaysShown />
        {this.props.children || <DefaultComponent />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: bit confusing this code / how  {this.props.children || <DefaultComponent />} will render my components inside . where should i configure

Comment: see this is my code snippet                                                                              <Router history={browserHistory}>
<Route name="index" path="/Referral" component={App} />
<Route name="Referral" path="/Referral/details(/:pathParam)" component={UserDetails} />
<Route name="notifications" path="/Referral/notifications" component={Notifications} />
<Route name="report" path="/Referral/report" component={Report} />
<Route name="invalidURL" path="*" component={Page404} />

Comment: `this.props.children` will be the component that you specify inside your routes. So in this case on `/about` `this.props.children` will be `<About />`.

Comment: ok i understood but how to change the header text based on rendered components dynamically here . i.e in header text should be changed to Home, User etc based on components

Comment: is it possible pass from reducer store or do u have any other idea

Comment: Passing from store sounds like a good option. You can also [listen to a route change and put in the content based on that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39972785/sync-redux-store-with-react-router-route-location-update-header-on-route-change).  If that doesn't work  it would probably be best to keep it like you had it and [render the Header in every route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40930108/dynamic-react-redux-header-component-in-large-application).

Comment: You can wrap the routes in the redux `Provider`, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34797666/6941627).

Comment: yup i did  wrap the all components inside of provider . my question is assume now header is fixed and components will be update   as you suggested  return (
      <div>
        <HeaderAlwaysShown />
        {this.props.children || <DefaultComponent />}
      </div>
    )     then through Router(react-router)  components will update  so now if i  rendering second page  . before to render should i call a action for change header text. if so then when to dispatch an action , and from  which components should i do this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Redux expert. But this seems like a different question anyways, maybe ask a separate question with that specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assume this is your layout.jsx file

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
    <Header/>
    <YourRouterHandler>
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

For your header - create store, and update it according to your currently rendered page. And take its value in your `<Header/>`

Comment: this is how am doing but Header component am calling in each page (component) as first header like below                                                    render (){                                                                                                           return ( <div> <Header/><div>page 1</div>                                                                                             )             I each component am  calling Header component as first

Comment: You don't understand, the code i provided above - should be your in your root component, whule <YourRouteHandler/> Should render current page, so the <Header/> Will never be re-rendered unless you change data in it.

Comment: <YourRouterHandler> means my component which has navigation link to another page right